# To fetch ALTERNATE records from a 2 tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, validation

I have 2 tables like below and want to fetch the alternate records from the table like below o/p
[image]
pleas help me how this is possible ??

Comment: The question is unclear, what do you want to do? please post an example. also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does the expected result really match the given data? How come you want just those 4 rows to be returned - first date only or something else?

Comment: Most people here want sample data and expected result as properly formatted text, not as images. (Can't copy-and-paste from an image, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like

```
SELECT * FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2
ORDER BY value_date, ccpair, type
```

I don't guarantee you'll get the currency pairs in the exact order you specified in the question on each day but if there is only one currency pair per day in each table and they're reliably represented (when there is a long there is definitely a matching short) then this will churn out data where rows are paired up "long short long short" like

```
date1, pair1, long
date1, pair1, short
date1, pair2, long
date1, pair2, short
date2, pair1, long
date2, pair1, short
```

If there isn't necessarily a matching record in each table, advise

Side note it would perhaps be more normal and or reliable to use a join here and connect t1 to t2 on the currency pair and the date and use the "long and short are on the same row" result set in the front end, than to churn out two rows

In other words, have the front end be responsible for the emitting of paired rows, not the back end. Relating data by position alone early in the data supply pipeline is risky.